# Nested linked lists in C

Tags: c, list, nested, structure

I'm trying to implement a nested linked list in C, that will be used for a hierarchical menu. However, the GCC (v4.9.3-1) is complaining to nested structures, and I have no idea how to fix this. Here is the minimum (non)working example.

Is this nesting even possible in C?

**main.c**

```
#include "menu.h"

int main(void) {
    Init_Menu();
    return 0;
}
```

**menu.c**

```
#include "menu.h"

MenuItem_t LVL_0_MainMenu = {
    .size = 0,
};

MenuItem_t LVL_1_Measurements = {
    .size = 0,
};

void Init_Menu(void) {
    Menu_Add_Child(&LVL_0_MainMenu, &LVL_1_Measurements);
}

void Menu_Add_Child(MenuItem_t *parent, MenuItem_t *child) {
    parent->children[parent->size] = child;
    child->parent = parent;
    parent->size++;
}
```

**menu.h**

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char size;
    MenuItem_t children[10];
    MenuItem_t *parent;
} MenuItem_t;

extern MenuItem_t LVL_0_MainMenu;
extern MenuItem_t LVL_1_Measurements;

void Init_Menu(void);
void Menu_Add_Child(MenuItem_t *parent, MenuItem_t *child);
```

---

Based on answers by @bolov and @sps (once again, thanks to both of them), here is the minimum working example:

**main.c**

```
#include "menu.h"

int main(void) {
    Init_Menu();
    return 0;
}
```

**menu.c**

```
#include "menu.h"

MenuItem_t LVL_0_MainMenu = {
    .size = 0,
};

MenuItem_t LVL_1_Measurements = {
    .size = 0,
};

void Init_Menu(void) {
    Menu_Add_Child(&LVL_0_MainMenu, &LVL_1_Measurements);
}

void Menu_Add_Child(MenuItem_t *parent, MenuItem_t *child) {
    parent->children[parent->size] = child;
    child->parent = parent;
    parent->size++;
}
```

**menu.h**

```
struct MenuItem_t {
    unsigned char size;
    struct MenuItem_t *children[10];
    struct MenuItem_t *parent;
};

typedef struct MenuItem_t MenuItem_t;

extern MenuItem_t LVL_0_MainMenu;
extern MenuItem_t LVL_1_Measurements;

void Init_Menu(void);
void Menu_Add_Child(MenuItem_t *parent, MenuItem_t *child);
```

The difference between this corrected program and the original (non)working program, is that the children array is defined as an array of pointers to variables of the type `MenuItem_t` instead of the array of variables of the same type. The other difference is that a nested list (inside the structure) should also contain the keyword `struct` as @bolov explained.

Comment: follow **any** tutorial on C linked lists. And you will see how to define your node structure.

Comment: `GCC (v4.9.3-1) is complaining to nested structures` Can you include a quote of these 'complaints'? Whenever you post a question that involves an error/warning message, you should include it, so people don't have to guess what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll keep that in mind for future questions! I won't post errors now, as bolov and sps have answered my question. I'll post a complete solution in my first post once I test everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `struct` for the type used inside itself, even if you typedef it later on.

E.g. this won't work:

```
struct X_ {
  X* next;
};

typedef struct X_ X;
```

But this will

```
struct X_ {
  struct X_* next;
};
```

---

As a side note, I really don't like this form:

```
typedef struct {
} X;
```

I use:

```
struct X {
};
typedef struct X X;
```

But maybe this is just me being more fond of `C++`.

If you want to use that form, it's the same: you need to add `struct` and it works:

```
typedef struct {
  struct X2* next;
} X2;
```

---

regarding:

```
struct X {
   struct X arr[10];
};
```

You can't have that! The array is just in our way to understand why. So let's simplify:

```
struct X {
   int a;
   struct X var;
};
```

This can't be. What size would `X` be? `sizeof(X) = sizeof(int) + sizeof(X) + padding`. Do you see the problem? All you can do is have a pointer to `X`, but not an object `X` inside `X`.

Returning to your array. You need dynamic arrays:

```
struct X {
   struct X* arr;
   int arr_size;
};
```

It gets more complicated as you need to manage the memory (`malloc`/`free` fun), but you can't avoid it.

Comment: I agree with you on the dislike of that form... It's really gross

Comment: I fixed it in a way that I removed a `typedef` and added the `struct` keyword before all `MenuItem_t`. Now the GCC complains to array `struct MenuItem_t children[10]` with the following error: _array type has incomplete element type_.

Comment: @Marko you can't have that. Think about it: what size would `MenuItem_t` be?

Comment: What I actually want is to store an array of pointers to other (predefined number of) `MenuItem_t` variables. Can this be done? As for the "typedef form", I don't have that experience to like/dislike any form, I'm just using a form that programmers-that-write-header-files-for-microcontrollers use :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot do,

```
typedef struct {
    SomeName_t some_var;
} SomeName_t;
```

You need to do,

```
typedef struct somename {
    struct somename some_var;
} SomeName_t;
```

Also, a struct cannot have a member which is an array of structure itself. However, a struct can have a member which is an array of pointer to the same structure.

```
struct foo {
    struct foo foo_arr[10];      /* Will give error */
    struct foo *foo_ptr_arr[10]; /* Legal */
};
```

However, I dont see a reason that your `children` member should be an array of struct anyways. Because, as can be seen in `menu.c`, you are doing

```
    parent->children[parent->size] = child;
```

where the type of `child` is `MenuItem_t *`. So I think you basically wanted `MenuItem_t.children` to be an array of `MenuItem_t *`, and not an array of `MenuItem_t`.

So making this change should resolve your issue:

**menu.h**

```
typedef struct menuitem {
    unsigned char size;
    /* MenuItem_t children[10]; */  /* Not possible */
    struct menuitem *children[10];  /* This is what you want to do */
    struct menutem *parent;
} MenuItem_t;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited my first post to include these solutions.